# Map<String, String> with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have JPA entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE")
public class Attribute {

    //ID stuff

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And the other entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE_GROUP")
public class AttributeGroup {

    //ID stuff

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "ATTRIBUTE")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "NAME")
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    public void createAttribute(String name, String value) {
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
        attribute.setName(name);
        attribute.setValue(value);
        attribute.setAttributeGroup(this);
        attributes.put(name, value);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

I need to have a map in `AttributeGroup` entity which will have `Attribute`'s name as a key and `Attribute`'s value as a value.

The current approach does not work for me. When I am trying to persist records to the database it generates exception that transaction is marked as roolback only. I don't know if it is even the write way to do this, well if it is not working obviously it is not.

How can I achieve this in JPA to have a map in `AttributeGroup` made from `Attribute` name/value paired object?

I am using Hibernate via EntityManager.

Comment: is it compulsory to use hibernate annotations? can't we go for xml mapping?

Comment: Yes it is, I need to stick to JPA approach, hibernate is just an implementation, as we might be migrating to OpenJPA in future.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the code causing it. Also, what's the point of the Attribute entity? You don't seem to use it. You create a new Attribute in your method but don't do anything with it.

Comment: I am referencing it with the AttributeGroup table: attribute.setAttributeGroup(this);

Comment: Yeah, but your code does nothing there. The instance of `attribute` is created, you do call `attribute.setAttributeGroup(this)` but then you do nothing with it (you don't persist it for example), so everything you do is lost.

Comment: I am persisting everything later, I have other tables as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an element collection being stored in the same table as another entity, since the name/value pair cannot both be an element and an entity.  Elements do not have identity, and will not have any of the other fields maintained.

What you might do instead is have a 1:M or M:M to Attribute that uses the name as the map key.  You can then expose the map with name/Attribute pairs to the application directly, or create additional accessors that convert the map to a Map if required.  Because of identity though, it might be a better idea to expose and use Attributes directly.

If this is not desirable, then using a String/String pairing is possible through an element collection, but you will not be able to reuse the same table as an entity or in other element collection mappings.  The table will need a foreign key back to the AttributeGroup as well as fields for the name/value pairs, which will cause problems if reused.